# R Downloading multiple file from FTP using Rcurl

Tags: r, loops, download, rcurl

I'm a new R. user. 
I am trying to download 7.000 files(.nc format) from ftp server ( which I got from user and password). On the website, each file is a link to download. I would like to download all the files (.nc).

I thank anyone who can help me how to run those jobs in R. Just an example what I have tried to do using Rcurl and a loop and informs me: cannot download all files.

```
library(RCurl)

url<- "ftp://ftp.my.link.fr/1234/"
userpwd <- userpwd="user:password"
destination <- "/Users/ME/Documents"
filenames <- getURL(url, userpwd="user:password", 
ftp.use.epsv = FALSE, dirlistonly = TRUE)

for(i in seq_along(url)){
  download.file(url[i], destination[i], mode="wb")
}
```

how can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

The first thing you'd see is that the files in your directory, ie the object *filenames*, would be listed as one long string. To obtain an object of all file names as a character vector, you may try:

```
    files <- unlist(strsplit(filenames, '\n'))
```

From here on, it's simply a matter of looping through all the files in the directory. I recommend you use the curl package, not Rcurl, to download the files, as it's easier to supply auth info for every download request.

```
    library(curl)
    h <- new_handle()
    handle_setopt(h, userpwd = "user:pwd")
```

and then

```
    lapply(files, function(filename){
    curl_download(paste(url, filename, sep = ""), destfile = filename, handle = h)
    })
```

Comment: Hi Mohit, thank you for your help. I did what you told me. However, there is another type of error. ... Error in curl_download(paste(url, files[i], sep = ""), destfile = files[i],  : 
  FTP: couldn't retrieve (RETR failed) the specified file

Comment: hey @Gustavo, I'm not quite sure why that error comes, the for loop had worked for me, but now I'm getting the same error as you mentioned. Can you use how the lapply function and see if it works for you?