# How to import multiple CSV files from FTP in R

Tags: r, csv, import, ftp

I want to import multiple csv files from FTP Server in R (R is local / on my mac). Files should be stored in an R-object, e. g. in a `data.frame`.

I only know how to import a single file in a `dataframe`:

```
url <- "ftp://xxx/testfolder/test.csv" 
userpwd = "xxx:yyy"
text_data <- getURL(url, userpwd = userpwd, connecttimeout = 60)
df <- read.csv(text = text_data, header = TRUE)
```

How can I apply it on several files. I guess applying function `apply` can help but I don not really know how to do it.

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/48105838/786542

Comment: @mako212 running last query results in "access denied".

Comment: @ Tung Think its hardly adaptable to importing files from ftp

Comment: @flobrr There are two key parts here, 1) retrieve multiple files from FTP 2) read in multiple `.csv` files. Tung's link probably answers the second part.

Comment: And you still need to provide your authentication credentials, in reference to the link

Comment: @Mako212. Yes, I tried a lot, but i do not get it and here is no solution to import mulltiple files from ftp that works for me

Comment: Can you provide access to an `ftp` server that replicates your problem? If the existing solutions don't work, there is no way for anyone to test a solution without a way to reproduce the problem.

Comment: sorry, i can not. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39705379/r-downloading-multiple-file-from-ftp-using-rcurl/39706760#39706760] works till last query. Then I get error `Error in curl_download(paste(url, filename, sep = ""), destfile = filename,  : Failed initialization`